# Handle exception of Blanked EditText and EditText With Character?(better get in disrciption)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, runtimeexception

I created an application for the converting Currency from Dollar to Rupee. As I entered the amount in the dollar it converts to Rupee after pressing the `button`. The `Variable` type of resulted amount is `double`. Now if I Entered the `character`  in The EditText instead of Number and press the `button` the Application gets Crashed. The Same thing is happening when I keep the EditText blank and press the `button`. It is obvious that we can not convert the character into `double` i.e Rupee. Now How to handle these `Run Time Errors` by keeping about application not getting a crashed. I tried to search the similar question but not get satisfied with that. (Ask me for Extra information regarding question if you need).

> ActivityMain.java

```
           package com.example.admin.convertcurrency;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void ButtonClicked(View view) {



            EditText EnteredAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnteredAmount);


            Log.i("Amount Entered", EnteredAmount.getText().toString());

            Double ConvertedAmount = (Double.parseDouble(EnteredAmount.getText().toString()));
            Double Rupees = ConvertedAmount * 71.64;


            Log.i("Converted Amount", String.valueOf(Rupees));


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("%.2f",Rupees) + "Rs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter The Number Instead..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

> LogCat Error Log(After typed Single "A" character in EditText)

```
09-09 20:30:54.415 30894-30894/com.example.admin.convertcurrency E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.convertcurrency, PID: 30894
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "a"
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at com.example.admin.convertcurrency.MainActivity.ButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:44)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

> LogCat Error Log(After keeping the EditText as blank)

```
 09-09 19:00:44.031 8951-8951/com.example.admin.convertcurrency E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.convertcurrency, PID: 8951
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at com.example.admin.convertcurrency.MainActivity.ButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:23)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- you need to force the keyboard to be numeric only and this can be done by using `inputType`in you `EditText` **XML** :

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

2- you need to handle the case of empty string (blank input)

```
if(EnteredAmount.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you must enter a value to converted",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

3- for making sure user does not copy a char in the `EditText` you can create a simple method for that :

```
private boolean containsChar(String input){
   return input.contains("A-Za-z ");
   // you can add any special chars need to avoid after A-Za-z for example A-Za-z+-*/
}
```

so your final onClick can be like that

```
String s = EnteredAmount.getText().toString();
if(s.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you must enter a value to converted",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(containsChar(s)){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "can't contain chars",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
   // do operation here
}
```

Comment: can you add more attribute for the spaces. because it gives an error while I entered the space in EditText.

Comment: you can add it like the "A-Za-z*-+/ " I'll edit answer you can search for regular expressions for more info >> edited

Comment: as i you told implemented that containsChar method but it still cant handle that error and app continue to crashing.

Comment: https://ideone.com/EJHuE1 the method works well as expected you can test too with different scenarios if need. if you try to cover different cases tell me

Answer (score 0):

To prevent anything but decimal numbers being entered into your input, add the following property to your EditText in XML:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

To prevent your app from crashing when making a conversion, check to see if the length of the input is greater than 0:

```
String enteredAmount = EnteredAmount.getText().toString();
if (enteredAmount.length > 0) {
    Double ConvertedAmount = (Double.parseDouble(EnteredAmount.getText().toString()));
    Double Rupees = ConvertedAmount * 71.64;


    Log.i("Converted Amount", String.valueOf(Rupees));


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("%.2f",Rupees) + "Rs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    //do nothing or notify the user that the input can't be empty"
}
```

Comment: android:inputType="numberDecimal"   this method not looking sufficient. can try to generate logic for the same

Comment: What do you mean by "not looking sufficient"? It will prevent users from entering anything but `01234567890.`.

Comment: as per the application standard probably it is the best method. but i want handle different scenarios like keeping blank, Enter character, Enter Space. and for each different scenarios i want different Toast. As i am learner, i need to know these things first rather than going directly to Best. Thank you.

Comment: i am still noob in android. and i want to learn all the attributes of that. I  really appreciate your answer but i was expecting some java logic to handle that those situations.... thank you